# How to show incomplete degree on resume

Tags: job-search, resume, education, degree, computer-science

For my university, I was in the Bachelor's of Science Specialist in Computer Science program. The specialist program requires 40 CS courses (4 years worth) completed, and the Major Program only requires 25 (basically, the specialist is the major plus more). I had 39/40 courses finished for the Bachelor's of Science in Specialist in Computer Science program. And I have 25/25 courses completed for the Major in Computer Science program. Basically, I completed the courses for the Major but I was officially not in the Major Program, I am officially in the Specialist program.

What should I put on my resume? I was thinking leaving the Specialist off, since although I was just 1 course away from completing it, it is not completed.

But since I finished the courses for the Major (even though I'm not officially in the Major Program), do you think I can put down Major in CS on my resume?

And simply apply for places that don't require a degree? I know CS (since I completed the courses for a major and completed 39/40 courses for a Specialist in CS) so I want to show it on my resume but don't know how to put it.

Also, I plan on completing my last course in summer 2023 but not officially registered for the summer course yet (registration starts much later).

Edited for conciseness.

Also, it's been 2 years since I stopped attending university and haven't worked a tech job during that time. I plan on getting back into the tech industry now.

[Screenshot of my university status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjSAF.png)

[University status detailed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ajVQ.png)

Comment: @joeqwerty Fair enough. Basically it's been 2 years since I attended university and worked in the tech industry. If I plan on finishing my last course for the Bachelor's of Science in Specialist Computer Science in the Summer 2023, do you still think I should leave it off resume till I finish? I'm applying for tech jobs now until summer and I want a way to show I know CS and took courses on them (about 39/40 courses for the Bachelor's of Science in Specialist CS, so I mean I know CS)

Comment: Can you add the info in this comment to your post? It's quite relevant since it means you have the option of listing an [expected graduation date](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13730) instead of working with an "incomplete" degree. Also check [Incomplete Degree - How to phrase this on resume or cover letter?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/54888) and [Discontinued Master's Degree on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11653)

Comment: “do you think I can put down Major in CS on my resume?” - Only if you received a degree. Showing an expected **graduation date** should be enough to show your knowledge. There is a pretty big difference between a B.S in Computer Science and a Major in Computer Science. Speaking from experience don’t indicate your start date, you will be ask, the reason it’s taken a decade.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incomplete Degree - How to phrase this on resume or cover letter?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54888/incomplete-degree-how-to-phrase-this-on-resume-or-cover-letter) [Listing incomplete college degree on resume after several years of experience?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/87766/listing-incomplete-college-degree-on-resume-after-several-years-of-experience?rq=1)

Comment: @Lilienthal I marked this question and answered and asked it in a seperate question instead (didn't want to ask one question, then edit my post to a different situation). Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say "attended," show the major you want to show, and give the years.  Discuss in the interview if needed.  Don't draw attention to it by putting a ton of words there, highlight your skills in other portions of the resume.  My opinion is that putting a long description of why it happened plays against the main reason people like degrees - it shows you can finish a big thing.

Answer (score 6):

You can probably write :

University ABC (2000 - 2002) -
B.S.  in Computer Science (**Incomplete**)

(**Note**: I completed 39 out of 40 required courses for a BS degree)

Comment: Maybe this would look better? Attended University ABC (2000 - 2002) - B.S. in Computer Science (97,5% complete)

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it:

University ABC (2000 - 2002) - B.S. in Computer Science (98% **complete**)